# OpenGL C#, loading textures in upside down

Tags: c#, opengl, graphics, textures, opentk

Is there a way to load images into openGL with the y-coords flipped? (upside down). I'm using the .NET Bitmap and BitmapData classes, and passing BitmapData.Scan0 to OpenGL.

Flipping the Bitmap on the CPU using `.RotateFlip()` is too slow.

Aside from flipping all of the texcoords, can I solve this problem in our engine?

Comment: Are you sure that flipping textures is a bottleneck in your program?

Comment: Yes, things like FPS counters have thier text drawn on the CPU and set to a texture for rendering to the screen on the GPU. Having to flip it every frame takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no. OpenGl takes a pointer to an image as texture data, and I never seen any way to tell him to flip the lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you render using a fragment shader, you get to interpret the u, v coordinates anyway you want. Turning them upside down should be trivial and (nearly) free.

Other than that, just flip your texture coordinates. It should not be difficult to achieve this.

Comment: We are writing an engine. Flipping the texcoords is what we are doing at the moment. But it causes other problems such as textures that were rendered to using framebuffers are upside down. Users of an engine should also expect that the texcoords supplied in the model are the same as the ones they use in thier shaders. Unfortunatly it's not an option...

Comment: @Hannesh: Fixed function pipeline offers the GL_TEXTURE matrix, so you could `glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE); glScalef(1, -1, 1);` or, like suggested do it in the shader.

Comment: As mentioned, we are writing an engine and therefore have no control over the shaders that users write.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just alter your texture coordinates to achieve the desired flip.

Answer (score -2):

(edit: Disregard, question is textures instead of DrawPixels)

This worked for me in C++.

Q: "How can I make glDrawPixels() draw an image flipped upside down?"

A: "Try glPixelZoom( 1.0, -1.0 ). Similarly, an image can be flipped left to right with glPixelZoom(). Note that you may have to adjust your raster position to position the image correctly."

src: http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/sig97/gotchas.htm